How to manage multiple states in a single BLoC without affecting the UI?
I'm developing a Flutter application using the BLoC pattern. I have a single UI page that interacts with a BLoC that handles 5 events and 10 states. My requirement is as follows:
When I fire an event and emit a specific state (e.g., StateA), I want the rest of the UI (which depends on other states) to remain unaffected.
Currently, I am preventing unwanted rebuilds by creating multiple BLoCs, which feels redundant and complicates my architecture.
What is the best way to emit a specific state from a single BLoC without causing the entire UI to rebuild or get affected? Are there design patterns or approaches within the BLoC architecture that can help achieve this?
Additional Context:

I want to maintain a clean architecture with a single BLoC managing
multiple states.   Using BlocBuilder for the entire UI leads to
unwanted rebuilds when only one state changes.
I would prefer to  avoid creating multiple BLoCs for different
states/events if possible.


for every UI part(widgets) wrap it in BlocSelector, as in answer, and set condition for every this UI parts. also you could use buildWhen  callback

@VladyslavUlianytskyi  I checked the official document and it worked for me. Thanks

BlocSelector (context.select) is the default method for only listen to a part of state changes.
https://bloclibrary.dev/flutter-bloc-concepts/#contextselect
